# CoreData performance using one-to-many relationships

Tags: performance, core-data

I have an iPad application which continuously records the finger position (up to 30 times per second) if it is on screen and saves a 'Sample'-Object to Core Data for each dataset recorded. After a while, maybe two or three minutes, this process or at least the user feedback gets really slow. If I shut down the App and relaunch it is slow right from the start, but deleting the persistent store helps to get it back to the original performance. Therefore I think the problem should have to do with the data storage.

I have tried to detect the problem with the time profiler, but most of the time is consumed by system libraries and non-Objective-C code. If I turn those off for the profiling, what remains the most time consuming method is the initialization of the sample object:

```
@implementation Sample (Create)
+(Sample *)sampleWithTime:(double)time
             xValue:(double)x
             yValue:(double)y
          eventType:(EventType)event
        chillStatus:(BOOL)chill 
        participant:(Participant *)whoListened
              track:(Track *)whichTrack
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
   Sample *sample; 
   if (!sample) {
    sample = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sample" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     sample.time = time;
     sample.x = x;
     sample.y = y;
     sample.event = event;
     sample.chillStatus = chill;
     sample.whichTrack = whichTrack;
     sample.whoListened = whoListened;
   }
   return sample;
}
```

sample.whichTrack = which track; sets up the relationship to the track-object (ManagedObject subclass, refers to the music, which is playing) given to the method. It is a one-to-many relationship in the sense that there is only one track per sample, but lots of samples per track.This line then consumes 87% of the time of the whole method, even though the next line is doing exactly the same and needs almost nothing compared to that.

Does this make any sense to search for the problem here? Can the database get that much slower  because the set of the objects in the relationship become bigger and have to be copied to add an object or something like that? Is there anything I can do to improve the performance? The database as a file does not become big at all, it is still less than 1 MB.

Comment: do you save after each sample? are the samples done for the same `Track` in these 3 minutes?

Comment: Yes, it gets slow when I have to many 'Samples' for one 'Track'. If I record something for another 'Track' it starts fast and slows down after a while as well. I am not doing any explicit saves while recording, only at the end. 
I wonder if adding a 'Sample' to the relationship is time consuming, because the set is getting large and has to be copied in the background everytime I add something. That would make sense as for the other relationship to the 'participant' (='whoListened') the amount does not get that large, because I tend to change that every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It make a lot of sense to search the problem there.

I assume you set your `whichTrack` (to-one) relationship with an inverse `samples` (to-many) relationship on the `Track` object.

You take 30 `Sample`s/sec ==> 3min of sampling on the same `Track` will hold: 5400 objects in the to-many relationship. this relationship is maintained on both ends, this means that whenever you insert a new sample, the entire set of objects (at least their faults) must be fetched from the store (if not already faulted).
If you save after each new `Sample` and release you context (reset or refresh the `Track` object) will require a re-fetch of all existing items in the to-many relationship the next time you access the `Track` item.

I would try to first remove the inverse relationship (the to-many side of the `Track` entity) and see how it behave.
Watch out as this will eliminate any cascading upon `Track` deletion (of `Sample` objects).

If you still need cascading upon `Track` deletion, you could add it yourself by adding a `prepareForDeletion` implementation to your `Track` entity.

Another solution (more elegant) will be to shard your samples into a `SampleContainer` object.
A `Track` object will have a to-many relationship to `SampleContainer`.
Each container will be limited to 'N' samples.
When a container is filled, add a new container to the `Track`.

In addition to all that:
You could perform a save only every 'T' time interval. this will further reduce store access   (saves), BUT this might not suit you as you might loose `Sample`s if the user terminate the application between 2 saves (you can always save before going to background).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried the first approach now and it seems to work fine and really fast, but I might go for the containers of objects when I find some time, as I agree that that would be more elegant.
I have read a lot of arguments against using non-inverse relationships. So would I just change 'Inverse' to 'No inverse relationship' or should I do anything about the Destination or Delete Rule as well? Or could I prevent from accessing the to-many relationship in code as now I stopped setting it at all.

Comment: About the addition: I am not doing any explicit saves except for in viewWillDisappear or so. Does e. g. calling the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` method already provoke a save operation? I thought the system autosaves every so often, so I just need to make sure it happens in the end and I never had any problem with that.

Comment: This might also be a problem. There is no default save called on the context, you must trigger it yourself. saving 5000 objects at one go could take more than a minute on device.

Comment: You could (for now) simply remove the inverse, this will cancel the deletion rule as well. then, recreate the class file for the `Track` entity, and the to-many set of `Sample`s will not be there any longer.

Comment: Thanks, recreating the file is what I didn't think of!